# Trigger JavaScript custom event on selenium iframe element, as send_keys input values not persisting

Tags: javascript, selenium, iframe

Trying to trigger JavaScript 'change' event on an element that is present in the iframe. Below is my code trail

```
// get the iframe window
var iframeDoc = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow.document;

// get the target element
var targetElement = iframeDoc.querySelector("#some_id");

// add a listener to the target element to make sure the event is fired
targetElement.addEventListener("onchange", function(){console.log("change event triggered");});

// set value in the target element
targetElement.value = "abc";

// now build the custom event
var customEvent = iframeDoc.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
customEvent.intEvent("change", false, true);

// trigger the event on the element
targetElement.dispatchEvent(customEvent)

// now click on the save button
```

We are not getting any error after the last line execution and see the message in the console. However, the value entered by selenium is not retaining when clicking on `Save` button in the form.

Tech stack:
Java, IE 11, selenium 3.141.59
Disabled Native Events

Comment: Can you update the question with the relevant text based HTML please?

Comment: Will try to de-identify the data and see if I can post a sample code.

Comment: @supputuri can you add some information about the form ?

Comment: The page is either relying on a different event or is expecting a trusted event. Try `element.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'))`. I would also try to switch the context to the frame with Selenium before dispatching the event.

Comment: Tried with `input`, `change`, `blur`, `keydown`, `keypress`, and `keyup` events, but still the data is not saving. The difference I see is when I enter the data manually I see few Mutation Events that are not been triggering when entering the value using selenium.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the page behaves as expected on IE without Selenium? If so, like Florent said, try switching into the `iframe`.

Comment: @supputuri, could be that the field needs to be focused first `element.focus()`. Anyway it would be easier to understand why it's not working by monitoring the events and by looking at the code when the text is entered manually. I doubt that you'll find a solution by just asking the community to guess how the page is working.

Comment: I think @Lucan asks the right question. According to OP, *the assignment on `value` doesn't error out so, value is set. **That alone is enough.*** Even the `change` event fires and logs the instructed message. All that is left to ensure that OP is not doing something wrong somewhere else. Perhaps, `name` attribute is missing, some other JS is conflicting, page is cached to older version or some other usual stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Stated that a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help a lot (you are speaking abouot some values, some buttons and some form about we know nothing),

`onchange` is DOM element property to listen for a [`change`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) event, the actual event name is `change`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but unfortunately I could not find a common application where I can reproduce this issue with iframe. And I can't share the application details as it's not publicly accessible application.

Comment: Apart from this @supputuri , does it helps dispatching the `change` event?

Comment: I see the `change` event triggering but the values (on the form get cleared) are not retaining when clicked on the save.

Comment: Sorry @supputuri , but there are many things not clear... is the form in the outer page or in the iframe? The page loaded in the iframe is a third party page or a page under your control? You are speaking about values of a form, but there is no reference to them in your example code... Could you please try to clarify?